# Building spikes

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

Inspired by this building (United States Air Force Academy Cadet Chapel, Colorado)

[image]

Your task is simple, given a positive integer `n`, output the spiked building to size `n`

## Testcases

```
1
->
   ^
  /|\
 /.|.\
/..|..\
_______


2
->
   ^  ^
  /|\/|\
 /.|..|.\
/..|..|..\
__________


7
->
   ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^
  /|\/|\/|\/|\/|\/|\/|\
 /.|..|..|..|..|..|..|.\
/..|..|..|..|..|..|..|..\
_________________________
```

Trailing spaces are allowed

You are to output the string with newlines

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 30 bytes

```
_/¶_./¶×“ ∧σ¿⊘=8G℅H«⊙”Ｎ_.\¶_\⟲
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREMpXj8mL14PSChpWnNBxEIyc1OLgTJ6IOH4mpqaOJASvZgYoCIdBc@8gtISv9LcpNQiDU24HqBqkHx8TAzInKD8ksSSVA1N6///jf/rluUAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
_/¶_./¶
```

Print the first two columns.

```
×“ ∧σ¿⊘=8G℅H«⊙”Ｎ
```

Print the middle columns repeated the appropriate number of times.

```
_.\¶_\
```

Print the last two columns.

```
⟲
```

Rotate to orient the output correctly.

Answer (score 10):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 80 bytes

```javascript
n=>`   ^ 
  /|\\
 /.|.\\
/..|..\\
___`.replace(/.[_|^]./g,'$&'.repeat(n))+'____'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBDsIgFAX3PcVbGIFUP7rWehGxlCBtaAg0beOKuyNdzeRl3mx@ZrOrX/ZrTF9Xxq7E7jUA6NEAMivVQFKmSkmVh2itB1rdEox1XNJb5/5Dcrqw05kduzM7j0K0rIaalTGt4B4d7g94PCtvVdpWwKa4peAopImP3NeHiioyUf4)

Comment: brilliant! this is a really smart solution :D

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 81 bytes

```py
lambda n:f" {'  ^'*n}\n  "+'/|\\'*n+'\n /'+(d:='.|.'*n)+rf'\
/.{d}.\
_'+'_'*3*-~n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBCoMwEAXQvacY3PwkQ5OFixbBmwwVSwgttNMQ3Ijaq6dZvpe39fnV4ZZLTZPU9/J5xIV0TD3tILrD6SlK1DPCIdLIaA5gE8cJ/vCtLJcE6YLf4@mlm8GY4QZ3@WnN5aWrSeZqbf0D)

Thanks @UnrelatedString for -3 bytes, by teaching me about the `rf` string literal.
Thanks @AidenChow for -1 byte, by adding another f-string.
Thanks @tsh for -1 byte.

Wow, looks like this has become a bit of a community effort.

Comment: You, my friend, are a genius of python 3.8!

Comment: ...this is the first I've ever even thought about this, but looks like [raw string literals handle backslash-newline *perfectly* here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPSl1BXVtdQSFOXStPWz0mTwHE1a@JiYHx9dW1NVKsbNX1avSAQpraRWnqMVz6etUptXoxXEC18epaGsZAtSaa/wuKMvNKNNI0zDU1/wMA)

Comment: @UnrelatedString Wow, I've never seen `rf` string literals before. You learn something new every day...

Comment: [82 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcpBCoMwEEbhvacY3PyJA8nCgkXwJoPFEkILdRqCG1HPHrP8Hi/t2@ev/TPlEicpv2V9h4V0jC0dIJrR6SVK1DL8KVLJqPZgE8YJ7nQ1Wc4R0nh3hMtJA8YLnenr@7Al5a9uJprB2nID) using another f-string at the beginning.

Comment: `'+'_'*(3*n+4)` could be `_'+'_'*3*-~n`

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 30 bytes

```
»ε¥»₄τ2?»øƒ≈»₇τẋṀf`|^/\.`τ\_+§
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCu861wqXCu+KChM+EMj/Cu8O4xpLiiYjCu+KCh8+E4bqL4bmAZmB8Xi9cXC5gz4RcXF8rwqciLCIiLCI1Il0=)

Modified port of the Jelly answer.

```
»ε¥»₄τ                         # [2, 14, 19, 3]
      2         Ṁ              # Insert at position 2...
        »øƒ≈»₇τ                # [74, 125, 99]
       ?       ẋ               # Repeated <input> times
                 f             # Flatten the whole thing
                  `|^/\.`τ     # Decompress each from base with the key "|^/\."
                          \_+  # Append an underscore to each
                             § # Transpose, fill and join by newlines.
```

Old version below because I thought it was quite elegant.

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `C`, 42 bytes

```
` ^
/|
.|
.|
__`øM↵*` 
 
/
/.
__`øṀ↵½Zƛ÷$j
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJDIiwiIiwiYCBeXG4vfFxuLnxcbi58XG5fX2DDuE3ihrUqYCBcbiBcbi9cbi8uXG5fX2DDuOG5gOKGtcK9Wsabw7ckaiIsIiIsIjQiXQ==)

This is quite elegant but somewhat messy approach. I'm unsatisfied with the last bit, `vj` should work but it doesn't.

The first bit produces the string

```
 ^ 
/|\
.|.
.|.
___
```

Then repeats each row of that by the input.

Then, it creates

```
/\
/..\
____
```

by mirroring half of each line, and inserts the previous into that. Finally, the whole thing is centered.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 30 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“\ɓ^‘ẋ“£×“Œ¥‘jṃ“|/.\^””_;Ɱz⁶ṚY
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yYk5PjHjXMeLirG8g5tPjwdCB1dNKhpUCxrIc7m4G8Gn29GKCSuUAUb/1o47qqR43bHu6cFfn//39DcwA)**

#### How?

```
“\ɓ^‘ẋ“£×“Œ¥‘jṃ“|/.\^””_;Ɱz⁶ṚY - Main Link: integer, N
“\ɓ^‘                          - Code-page indices = [92, 155, 94]
     ẋ                         - repeat N times
      “£×“Œ¥‘                  - Code-page indices = [[2, 17], [19, 4]]
             j                 - join -> [2, 17, 92, 155, 94, ..., 92, 155, 94, 19, 4]
               “|/.\^”         - list of characters = "|/.\^"
              ṃ                - convert to base 5 using "|/.\^" in place of the digits 12340
                         Ɱ     - map across these lists of characters with:
                      ”_;      -   concatenate to an '_' character
                          z⁶   - transpose with space characters as filler
                            Ṛ  - reverse
                             Y - join with newlines
                               - implicit print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>124</s> <s>91</s> <s>90</s></sup> 88 bytes

```python
lambda n:[print(('   /_  /._'+' /.._^|||_ \.._'*n+'  \._   \_')[i::5])for i in range(5)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYpBCoMwEEWv8neTVNBFkULAk5g4RGzagI4S3BRy93QWj//4vOt3f095tjT5tsdj3SLEzVfJchtDAAZWeqaOdHpeaq0Mr0YP0U9VA3gmO2fnxmDTWZCRBSXK521GG1oyL9v@)

Comment: 91: `lambda n:[print(('   /_  /._'+' /.._^|||_ \\.._'*n+'  \\._   \\_')[i::5])for i in range(5)]`

Comment: [Save one more byte with an r-string](https://tio.run/##DYrBCsIwEAV/5d02sRAPpQgBv6TbLikaDei2hF6E/HvcwzBzmON3vncde75z/6Tv9kjQOB@16OkcAbiKEYQGMgVZW2sCZku66FBt4WALWMjPJcZp8XmvKCiKmvT1dJNfenY33/8)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>42</s> <s>41</s> 35 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Y17•₅œ •₅вIи19Y·)˜"^|/.\"Åв'_δšζRJ»
```

-6 bytes porting [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243977/52210)

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/0tD8UcOiR02tRycrQBgXNnle2GFoGXlou@bpOUpxNfp6MUqHgaLq8ee2HF14bluQ16Hd//@bAAA) or [verify the first 10 test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R/iquSZV1BaYqWgZO@nw6XkX1oC4en8jzQ0f9Sw6FFT69HJChDGhU1@F3YYWkYe2q55eo5SXI2@XozSYaCoevy5LUcXntsW5HVo93@dQ9vs/wMA).

[See the previous revision for the original 42 and 41 bytes approaches.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/243931/2)

**Explanation:**

```python
Y              # Push 2
17             # Push 17
•₅œ •          # Push compressed 6021919
     ₅в        # Convert it to base-255 as list: [92,155,94]
       Iи      # Repeat this list the input amount of times
19             # Push 19
Y·             # Push 4 (2 doubled)
 )             # Wrap the stack into a list
  ˜            # Flatten
   "^|/.\"Åв  "# Convert it to custom base-"^|/.\"
               # (basically base-length, and then index into the string)
  δ            # Map over each inner list:
'_ š          '#  Prepend a "_" to each
    ζ          # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns, with a space " " as
               # default filler
     R         # Reverse the list of lists
      J        # Join each inner list together to a string
       »       # Join by newlines
               # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?* and *How to compress integer lists?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•₅œ •` is `6021919` and `•₅œ •₅в` is `[92,155,94]`.

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, <s>88</s> 73 bytes

Prompts for spikes.

Original

```
l←5 2⍴¯10↑'//.__'⋄c←5 3⍴' ^ /|\.|..|.___'⋄r←5 2⍴¯10↑'\ .\__'⋄⊃⊂[2]⍎'l,',((2×⎕)⍴'c,'),'r'
```

A simpler iindexing solution

```
m←5 7⍴'   ^     /|\   /.|.\ /..|..\_______'⋄m[;⍳2],m[;(3×⎕)⍴2+⍳3],m[;6 7]
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog APL Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tfy6Qaapg/qh3i7qCgkKcAgjo18SASL0avRggCaT0YuIhQP1Rd0tutPWj3s1GsTpAhobx4elAAzWB2o20gaLGYFEzBfPY/0DTuf6ncRlyqSuoc6VxGUFpcwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 69 bytes

```ruby
->n{'   ^ 
  /|\
 /.|.\
/..|..\
_______'.lines.each{|l|l[2,3]*=n}*''}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWl1BQSFOgUtBQb8mhktBX69GL4ZLXw9IAel4CFDXy8nMSy3WS01MzqiuyanJiTbSMY7Vss2r1VJXr/1fUJSZV6KQFm0c@x8A)

Lambda tacking *n* that multiplies inner substring *n* times for each line of the spike.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>64</s> 63 bytes

```
.+
 $&*$(  ^)¶  $&*$(/|\)¶ /$&*$(.|.)\¶/.$&*$(.|.).\¶__$&*3*___
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS0FFTUtFQ0EhTvPQNgUIR78mBsTRB3P0avQ0Yw5t09eD8/SA3Ph4INdYKz4@/v9/Qy4jLnMA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Just an application of Retina 1's string repetition operator. Note that repetition has higher precedence than concatenation so the string to be repeated has to be grouped (except in the case of repeating three `_`s which is achieved via a second repetition).

Answer (score 2):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate), 61 bytes

```
  ( ^ ){$~1}
  (/\|\\){$~1}
 /((.\|.){$~1})\\
/.$3.\\
_{#3+4}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qKDU9NS-1KLEkdcGCpaUlaboWN20VFDQU4hQ0q1XqDGu5gBz9mJqYGBhXX0NDL6ZGD8LVjInh0tdTMdYD0vHVysbaJrUQQ6BmLY42joUyAQ)

#### Explanation

`$~1` is the input number, and `{$~1}` repeats something that many times. So:

```
  ( ^ ){$~1}
```

Two spaces, followed by  `^`  N times.

```
  (/\|\\){$~1}
```

Two spaces, followed by `/|\` N times.

```
 /((.\|.){$~1})\\
```

`/`, followed by `.|.` N times (and capture that result as group 3), followed by `\`.

```
/.$3.\\
```

`/.`, followed by the contents of group 3 again, followed by `.\`.

```
_{#3+4}
```

`_` repeated len(group 3) + 4 times.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>76</s> 66 bytes

```
{`0:+?[4 4#"   /  /.  \\.   \\";2;,/(x,3 4)#" /..^||| \\.."],'"_"}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k/#eJxdTtsKwjAMfc9XlPqg4my0mww30A9xXrfuwnSbdIJg/Xcj4igNJycPOScnefQ6LaLZdhewYMQZY0gQjCUJETGPZezh5On5LJiSAIU4GGO+e8H33pgf+RsgZ0tqSR0CIJR93+kIMW0zVbTXXOj+nNbqmZbnplAibW94fyjdV22jUQb+Wq7w8qiuWdUUc91VtdKwhPkG6IUDEZoEKNmIBCjfCJrHXwGA/AsH7SC3HLbp5wstn4PhjIPhqgMrxIGd6dQHDOxkXA==)

- `?[a;2;b]` use [`splice`](https://k.miraheze.org/wiki/Splice) to insert `b` into `a` at position `2`

  - `4 4#"   /  /.  \\.   \\"` the initial array, representing the "sides" of the spiked building
  - `,/(x,3 4)#" /..^||| \\.."` `x` copies of the spikes
- `?[;;],"_"` append a `"_"` to each slice
- `` `0:+ `` transpose the above, and print to stdout

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 46 bytes

```
FlRsX,4.:"/\"J'|WR'.X,3PE'^AE'_X7{(l2,5)X:aPl}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhY39dxygoojdEz0rJT0Y5S81GvCg9T1InSMA1zV4xxd1eMjzKs1cox0TDUjrBIDcmohuqCaF0ebxEKZAA)

#### Explanation

First, we generate this list

```
["   ^"
 "  /|\"
 " /.|.\"
 "/..|..\"
 "_______"]
```

as follows:

```
RsX,4.:"/\"J'|WR'.X,3PE'^AE'_X7
                   ,3            ; Range(3): [0;1;2]
                '.X              ; Repeat . that many times: ["";".";".."]
            '|WR                 ; Wrap | in each of those strings: ["|";".|.";"..|.."]
       "/\"J                     ; Insert each of those strings between / and \:
                                 ; ["/|\";"/.|.\";"/..|..\"]
                     PE'^        ; Prepend "^" to the front of that list
                         AE'_X7  ; and append "_______" to the end:
                                 ; ["^";"/|\";"/.|.\";"/..|..\";"_______"]
   ,4                            ; Range(4): [0;1;2;3]
 sX                              ; Repeat space that many times: ["";" ";"  ";"   "]
R                                ; Reverse: ["   ";"  ";" ";""]
     .:                          ; Concatenate those two lists itemwise:
                                 ; ["   ^";"  /|\";" /.|.\";"/..|..\";"_______"]
```

Then we loop over each line, repeat the center section, and print the result:

```
Fl...{(l2,5)X:aPl}
Fl   {           }  ; For each line l
  ...               ; in the above list:
      (l   )        ;   The section of l
        2,5         ;   at indices range(2,5) i.e. [2;3;4] (modular 0-based indexing)
            X:      ;   string-repeat in place
              a     ;   (program argument) times
               Pl   ;   Print (the modified version of) l with a trailing newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 92 bytes

```lua
print(([[   ^ 
  /|\
 /.|.\
/..|..\
]]):gsub(".[_|^].",("%1"):rep(...))..('_'):rep(4+3*...))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704pzRxwYKlpSVpuhY3YwqKMvNKNDSioxUUFOIUuBQU9GtiuBT09Wr0Yrj09YAUkI6N1bRKLy5N0lDSi46viYvVU9LRUFI1VNK0Kkot0NDT09PU1NPTUI9XhwiYaBtrgQUhdkCtWhxtFAtlAgA) I feel like it can go a bit lower but don't want to play with it right now. Basically? a port of tsh's answer but with the underscores outside the initial string.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 70 bytes

```
.+
 $&$*1¶  $&$*2¶ /$&$*3\¶/.$&$*3.\¶__$&$*4__
1
  ^
2
/|\
3
.|.
4
___
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLQUVNRcvw0DYFMMMIyNAHMYxjDm3T1wOz9IDM@HgQ0yQ@nsuQS0EhjsuIS78mhsuYS69Gj8uEKz4@/v9/Q6CgOQA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Since Retina 0.8.2 can only repeat characters, placeholder digits are used for the four different building parts which are then substituted in afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 66 bytes

```
ri:R;SSSa"^  "R*NSS"/|\\"R*NS'/".|.":QR*'\N"/."QR*".\\"N'_"___"R)*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#cjam) I haven't golfed for a while, and longer since CJam, so this probably has significant optimizations available, but I was in the mood to try something. It basically just constructs the result line by line, with a couple minor optimizations by saving the size as a variable, saving the `".|."` construction as a variable since we re-use it, and using 3(n+1)+1 instead of 3n+4 to construct the bottom row.